# How to display information from db on the one template along with forms in django using class view?

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

I would like to have information from db on the right side of the page. How to display it on template? What I could add in class based view in order to see it on the template?

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <table>
                        {{ form }}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <h5>Problem:</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**view**

```
class SolutionCreate(CreateView):
        model = Solution
        template_name = 'analysis/create_solution.html'
    
        fields = [
            'problem',
            'research',
            'solutions',
            'resources',
            'plan',
            'test'
        ]
    
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = SolutionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/saved/')
    
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

not really clear to me what you want, but i assume you want extra context in the template.

use this in your createview

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
  // youre context
  return context
```

now the context is available in youre template

Comment: yes extra context alongside with forms in one template (on one page),
{{ form }} - not displayed at all if get_context_data present... could you please explain why?